# FormTextField is hidden behind keyboard despite SingleChildScrollView and no scaffold on page

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have seen similar questions asked but their situation was diiferent.

I have a Form, with several TextFormFields. The page scrolls just fine but with keyboard up, it won't show the lower fields. Other solutions here suggested adding a new tag to style.css. I have tried that. Did not work. Some suggested adding "resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true," to Scaffold, did that although this page does not have any Scaffold.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scrollbar(
      isAlwaysShown: true,
      controller: _scrollController,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                _buildSummary(),
                _buildDescription(),
                _buildHourRate(),
                _buildBudget(),
                _buildBudget(),
                ButtonCreate(
                  color: Color(0xFF18D191),
                  textForButton: "SUBMIT",
                  onPressShit: () {
                    if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                      return;
                    } else {
                      _formKey.currentState.save();

                      print(_summary);
                      print(_description);
                      print(_hourRate);
                      print(_totalBudget);

                      //Send to API
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The fields are built like this;

```
Widget _buildSummary() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Summary',
          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.purpleAccent.shade400),
          filled: true,
          fillColor: formFieldbackground.withOpacity(0.3)),
      maxLength: 45,
      validator: (String value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Summary is required';
        }

        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (String value) {
        _summary = value;
      },
    );
  }
```

This form is a `ModalBottomSheet.`

**See screenshots**

[image]

Comment: Try remove scrollbar and controller from the code only specify SingleChildScrollView@Firaun

Comment: @Assassin Tried that too. Didn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything you guys suggested but didn't work. However I learned that the problem isn't on form but the place (container) where form is being called.

So this form isn't actually a full screen but a bottomsheet. So it needs to have some height to pull out as tray. So once where I reduced the height of the container where this form is called then it started to work!!

It freaking doesn't make sense but somehow it works.

This is where the form is called;

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Center(
child: Container(
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.8, //previous height was 600;
```